# How to pass data using v-bind from view to component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wanted to pass a data from my database using `v-bind` and send the data to my component. I already tried iterating through my database using `v-for` in my template, however it prevents me from accessing the component when the database is empty and if it's not empty, it just fetch the first data `ID` in my database. I am using Parse and Mongodb as my database.

Here's my code below:

```
//Room.vue (View file)
<template>
   <PModal @close="toggleModal" @create="postAnnouncement()" v-bind:value="this.post_id">
    <p>{{ this.post_id }}</p>
    ...
    ...
   </PModal>
</template>

<script>
import Parse from 'parse';
import PModal from '@components/PModal.vue';
export default{
   components: { PModal }
   data(){
      return{
        post_id: '',
      }

   },
   methods: {
      postAnnouncement(){
        const Posts = Parse.Object.extend("Posts");
        const post = new Posts();

        ...
        post.save().then((post) => {
           this.post_id = `${post.id}`;
        }, (error) => {
            alert(`Failed to create announcement: ${error.message}`);
        });
     }
   },
}
</script>
```

And here's my code for my component:

```
//PModal.vue (component file)
<template>
   <button id="cancelBtn" class="float-right mt-6" @click="$emit('close')">Cancel</button>
   <button id="createBtn" class="float-left mt-6"@click="$emit('create')">Create</button>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  props: ['value`],
  data(){
    return {
      post_url: this.value,
    }
  },
  methods: {
     closeModal(){
       this.$emit('close')
     },
     createPost(){
       console.log("this is the passed ID:", this.post_url);
       this.$emit('create')
     },
  },
}
</script>
```

Is there something I'm overlooking here? Or are there any alternative methods for sending data from View to Component without using `v-bind`? Thank you in advance for anyone who helps!

Comment: Don't use `this` in template! `v-bind:value="this.post_id"` should be `:value="post_id"`. Same goes for `{{ this.post_id }}`. Should be `{{post_id}}`. Another problem is you don't seem to be declaring `PModal` component in parent (e.g: `components: { PModal }`). And import it, of course.

Comment: @tao My bad, I forgot to add and import my component ```PModal``` while editing this post. I tried ```:value="post_id"```, and ```{{ post_id }}```. it still doesn't show any result in my console. ```PModal``` still doesn't receive the data that I was passing.

Comment: In that case you might want to provide a *runnable* [mcve], using codesandbox.io or similar. What you posted here can't be run and it looks like it doesn't contain the source of the bug. Try to reproduce it in a sandbox and you'll give us a chance at pinpointing the cause.

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console?  i noticed a typo in the child component.  ``props: ['value`]`` (backtick ` and apostrophe ' used together) should be `props: ['value']`

Comment: None, there's no error actually. its just that it doesn't send the data ```:value = "post_id"``` to my component file instantly. It sends, but needs to be reloaded I think. Maybe I should make use of ```document.getElementById("createBtn").innerHTML = document.location.reload()``` inside createPost method in my component file.

Comment: I'll try to create a runnable minimal reproduction example using codesandbox.io to further point the cause of my problem. Thank you for your suggestion @tao.

Comment: What do you mean by *"instantly"* in "it doesn't send the data `:value="post_id"` instantly"? Of course it's not instantly. You're doing `post.save().then( p => ...)`. The `save()` part implies calling the backend, saving the post in db and getting back the post object. It's not going to be instant. If you would rather not open the modal until the response has returned, put a `v-if="post_id"` on `<PModal />`

Comment: The proper UX is to open the modal when the request leaves, display a loading indicator as long as the modal does not have `value` and display the content when you have a `value`. When the response returns and `post_id` gets populated in parent component, the modal will automatically update and switch content.